# Filter geojson or shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, convert, geojson, filter

I'm trying to create a geojson file with a few shapes of roads from OSM. Now, I've been able to get shapefiles of the greater region (province) these roads are in from http://download.geofabrik.de/ . I've also been able to convert a shape file to geojson using ogr2ogr. My problem is that it contains way too much data. Is there a way to filter a shapefile or geojson file by name, type or ID?

Comment: The usual approach is to import source OSM data into postgis, or to do a simple extract using the overpass API. Otherwise, which of your 4 questions is the one that should be answered?

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I've cleaned up the post a bit. The main issue is filtering. Thanks for your answer, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

ogr2ogr supports filtering, by using the where clause.
http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html